# What is the difference between the MMPI and the Myers–Briggs Type Inventory?

Tags: personality, test, clinical-psychology

Can you briefly explain in a non-technical way which are the main differences between the [Myers–Briggs Type Inventory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers-Briggs_Type_Indicator) and the [MMPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minnesota_Multiphasic_Personality_Inventory) test?

Comment: The MMPI is an abnormally bad test which is in use only for historical reasons. To help in diagnosis, use the SCID (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_Clinical_Interview_for_DSM-IV) and relevant specialized tests (for specific disorders or different aspects of intelligence/cognitive performance). To test personality, use a test relevant to the question you want to answer. There are general personality inventories for career decisions and most every other situation. Combine these with tests focusing on certain aspects of personality. Finally, leave diagnostics to a trained psychologist.

Comment: Revious, are you more interested in the difference between the two tests you mention, or in more recent and more scientifically valid alternatives? What exactly do you want to measure? Personality in general or specific traits? In what context and for which purpose do you want to use the test results? Clinical diagnosis, job applicant evaluation, research, ... ?

Comment: @what: maybe I should split the question in twice. I'm interested in clinical diagnosis.

Comment: I guess you should. You might read up a bit about clinical diagnosis, before you ask your question, but it can be quite complex, and if you just ask "which tests can one use)?" you'll get a list of hundreds of tests or more probably have your question voted to close because it is too broad. Think a bit about what exactly you want to know. If you want to understand it all, you need to study psychology ;-)

Comment: @what: I could narrow a lot the question to the real problem I'm interested in, but then it would become a self help question.. I've opened a generic question and clarified better in a comment

Comment: "This question was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content." I hesitate to say "**Looks Good** if nothing is wrong with this question", but I don't see any truly appropriate reasons to close it, I don't feel unsure of what's wrong with it, and the only edit I want to make is to roll back @JeromyAnglim's edit, because that would at least improve the length issue. Maybe this calls for a meta-question or two? In any case, `Looks Good`... :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MMPI calculates scale scores from dichotomous responses; hence those scale scores – the constructs of actual interpretive interest – are roughly continuous, or at least polytomous.

Yes, there are very many other tests that can assess personality traits that can aid in diagnosis. I'm not sure what you mean by "mature", and I hesitate to judge their sophistication.

I'm guessing by "INFJ" you're referring to the [Myers–Briggs Type Indicator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers-Briggs_Type_Indicator), of which "INFJ" is one available type. Typology is one primary difference from the [MMPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minnesota_Multiphasic_Personality_Inventory), which measures traits in terms of continuous dimensions. I'll leave the rest of the differences to Wikipedia for now.